# Does Jenkins offer a multiple build agents feature on VM like TeamCity?

Tags: java, jenkins, automated-tests, integration-testing

I've found that Teamcity offers the possibility to have multiple build agents (3 for free) that you can deploy on VMs to perform parallel testing (distribute the load) and by that have a certain gain of time of the execution of tests. Is that feature available in Jenkins as well? if yes, how many agents i can deploy?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: In think, No agent concept in Jenkins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do [distributed builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) in Jenkins to improve overall performance of your builds and to balance your load on different machines.

There is no limit on the quantity of slaves, however, the concept might differ from Teamcity's build agents. You might want to read up on the reference link to check, whether this is a possible solution for you.

Comment: Can you expand on 'no limit on the quantity of slaves'? Do the agents have to be added to Jenkins ahead of time or can they be dynamically created?

Comment: You can set up a master and install multiple agents as slaves. Thus, their number has to be defined ahead of time. Later, however, they can pick up their work dynamically. Hope that helps.

Comment: Each has to be added as a different node (computer) ahead of time, correct? You can't have a single "node" that dynamically spins up multiple copies of itself and increases its own available executors by the number of underlying vms

Comment: The master hosts your basic Jenkins installation, the agents are additional computers that you can set up to offload build projects from the master. Projects can later stick to a static agent or they can roam between them freely, if load balancing is an issue for your. This can be configured on a per-project-basis. Agents don't spawn dynamically.